# What is mutating tables in Oracle?

Tags: database, oracle, triggers

Tell me about mutating (changing) tables in Oracle.

I have read some articles about this, but I understand this in general terms. I would like to better understand mutating tables in Oracle.

I know that it has some problems, but I don't understand what they are or how to resolve them.

Can anybody tell me about this and give some examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully you have gone through the documentation, and that you couldn't understand the practical scenario where a `mutating table exception` might occur.

Per definition, Mutating table exceptions occur when we try to reference the triggering table in a query from within row-level trigger code.

Similar issue on Asktom, 
https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:290416059674

A nice article by Tim Hall, http://oracle-base.com/articles/9i/mutating-table-exceptions.php

More importantly, you must read **Using Compound DML Triggers to Avoid Mutating-Table Error** in the documentation, http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/triggers.htm#CHDFEBFJ

Comment: Thanks! I think this links and articles can help me to understand more.